# Avoid local() calls for tbb enumerable_thread_specific variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have a code which uses `tbb::enumerable_thread_specific` variables, and in the deep place of the call stack the thread local variables are used. The naive implementation leads to a lot of `local()` function calls.

Now I want to avoid `local()` function calls by passing parameters hierarchically. Is there a simpler way of doing this? I have many places with `local()` function calls if I do not pass Foo as a parameter, but the code would be messy if I do. I have been looking for possible usage of an array with size equal to the number of threads, and use `thread-id` to access the thread local variable, but it seems tbb does not provide that (in contrast to `omp_get_thread_num()` in OpenMP).

See more descriptions here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/804043

Answer (score 4):

Repeating and expanding my own answer from the TBB forum:

You can use `tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency()` and `tbb::this_task_arena::current_thread_index()` to implement array-based custom thread local storage. The first function gives the upper limit for the number of working threads; to a degree it's TBB equivalent for `omp_get_num_threads()`. The second one gives an index of the current thread within the limit, similarly to `omp_get_thread_num()`.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan.  Before suggesting something else, I would suggest you try to use `enumerable_thread_specific` if you can.  It provides one feature you may have trouble getting in general: each variable is guaranteed to line up on a cache line, which eliminates false sharing.

If you decide to manage your own thread-local storage, you must

1. Allocate the storage
2. Assign the storage to a thread, and
3. (potentially) free the storage.

Remember also that TBB does not guarantee a particular number of threads, though in general it will give you what you ask for.  Be careful of oversubscription.

You can use any storage that does not get reallocated, so `std::vector<T>` is out.  I'd suggest you use a `concurrent_vector<T>`, which doesn't get moved on expanding the array.

So you have to assign each thread a slot in the vector.  That index can be stored in TLS. Then use this index to fetch the instance from your `concurrent_vector`.  This can be an expensive operation if the vector is fragmented.

You can also use the `threadID` of the thread to hash into storage.  If you are willing to allocate a hash map once and never resize, this will work; otherwise you have to manage a chain of hash tables and walk through the chain looking for your instance.  If I remember right `enumerable_thread_specific` uses this technique.

You can see it is a non-trivial to implement your own version, and you'll always do better if you use a stack variable in each thread and pass that as a formal parameter.  Your problem may not be structured that way, though.

Comment: A good point on false sharing avoidance. As for storage reallocation and the rest - generally you are right, but if the upper bound on the number of participating threads can be known in advance, then it's easy to avoid reallocation.